# jquery closest; having trouble with code that worked before 1.5

Tags: jquery, closest, jquery-1.5

I had this bit of jQuery code

```
    var l = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.suggestable').length;
```

then i upgraded to 1.5 now i get this error

```
  Error: elem.nodeName is undefined
```

any idea why this nolonger works ?

Comment: Do you have a demo that reproduces this problem?

Comment: There is no change on the methods or functions u are talking about http://api.jquery.com/category/version/. you will have to provide some more code and markup

Comment: [Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ffvka/) using your code. Please provide code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: thanks you all I'll have to work up an example if I can the code I have in a secure site with login so I I can't show you the exact code

Comment: Just use http://jsfiddle.net/ to post an example.

Comment: I not familiar with how to creaate my own js fiddle  page but basically if you look at patrick dw's example and take out the click event so it looks like this
    var l = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.suggestable').length;
    alert( l );
  so that it is down on doc ready you will see the error

Comment: based on that wouldn't it always be 0 then since that would be window right ?

Comment: Try posting your HTML, meaning your whole `<fieldset>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the single `'` to double `"`? Like this:

```
var l = $(this).closest("fieldset").find(".suggestable").length;
```